# Как сохранить back up бэкап всех установленных программ, какие установлены на Windows 10. Идея в том, чтобы...?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, резервное-копирование

Как сохранить back up бэкап всех установленных программ, какие установлены на Windows 10 . Идея в том, чтобы например виндовс я переустановлю, и чтобы можно было одним щелчком или пару щелчками нажать, и все программы установились друг за дружкой, и не нужно было вспоминать чего не хватает для комфортной работы и воспоминать потом где достать, или как называется удобная программа . Есть такая система, кто сталкивался? Дело в том, я занимаюсь веб разработкой, и есть необходимость в разных программах, и вот я теперь думаю, что если с виндовс что то произойдет, довольно долго прийдется все восстанавливать, все программы, так как на изусть я их не помню . Устаналвивал кажду программу по мере необходимости . Хочеться сохранить, так как сказать, багаз инструментов, а не разбросить их по дороги и не собирать потом опять ))) Буду рад любой информацией

Comment: сохраняйте  копию диска или дисков (snapshot) целиком, плюс стандартные возможности резервирования/восстановления в Windows.

Comment: Задача довольно трудоемкая для винды если говорить о полной автоматизациии - лицензии и кастомные настройки программ. я сам админю *nix и использую Ansible, если добавите этот тег вам Дон Румата из Арканара может прислать весточку. Я раньше просто вел лог в тхт файле что я ставил. можно образы снимать с диска ... гляньте https://ninite.com/

Comment: @Hellseher, я тут))) моя рсс читалка сканит тег `ansible`, так что читаю каждый пост.

Comment: Теперь по теме: т.к. у винды нету пакетного менеджера, то всё разворачивание окружения становится в разы труднее, чем на linux. Чё у тебя за софт стоит? Поправь вопрос. Потому что именно его список будет определяющим фактором куда надо двигаться.