# Как сохранить бэкап Windows 10 Виндовс 10,настроек, всех программ установленных, настроек их, путей файлов сохранения?

Tags: windows, администрирование, резервное-копирование

Например, я переустановлю виндовс, чтобы можно было одним или парой щелчков установить все программы друг за дружкой, не нужно вспоминать, чего не хватает для комфортной работы, воспоминать потом, где достать или как называется удобная программа. Также, немаловажно, чтобы сохранились все настройки программ, а именно пути хранения файлов и тонкие настройки, чтобы плагины сохранились в Программах. Если такие имеются. Также чтобы сохранились все папки и названия папок в Windows (на любых дисках) , как в старому компьютере. Также чтобы Виндовс не был привязана к железу . Чтобы в одном компьютере например перестал работать виндовс, установил в другом компьютер этот виндовс со всеми программами, их настойками и их путями папок, где они находятся и пути папок сохраниний. В идеале конечно чтобы и папки название были такими же, как и в старом виндовсе, но уже установленые на новом компьютере. Ну еще одно, чтобы местолопжение ярлыков также сохранилось, как в старому компьютере

Может есть какое-то решение облачное для такой задачи ?
Есть такая система, кто сталкивался? Дело в том, что я занимаюсь веб разработкой и есть необходимость в разных программах, и вот я теперь думаю, что если с виндовс что-то произойдет, довольно долго придётся всё восстанавливать, все программы, так как наизусть я их не помню. Устанавливал каждую программу по мере необходимости. Хочется сохранить, так как сказать, багаж инструментов, а не разбросать их по дороге и не собирать потом опять :))). Буду рад любой информации.

P.S. О том, как я дошел до такой идеи. Думаю, что все началось с закладок . В те далекие времена это была опера, и я любил пользоваться закладками браузера, а еще больше экспресс-панелями (небольшими плиточками с изображением сайтов) Но вот незадача, когда слетал Виндовс, то слетали эти закладки. Потом я научился копировать файл в опере, где хранились эти закладки, и после установки нового Виндовс вставлял эти файлы в новую оперу. Потом научился пользоваться облачным решением от Опера, где можно было загружать туда экпресс панели, потом выгружать . Потом меня Опера достала, я нашел решение облачное решение для любого браузера, а именно Tabs Bool, туда можно входить с любого компьютера в свой акккаунт и все закладки подгружаются, не надо даже никуда закачивать . Потом следующим решением для комфортной работы стала программа Dekstop ok, которая сохраняет рассположение ярлыков в нужных места (ведь Вы знаете как Windows 10 при наличии двух мониторов любит эти ярлыки сбросить и закинуть в кучу) . И вот теперь я дошел до той черты, когда хочу бэкап -нуть ввесь виндовсь со всеми его настройками, и чтобы сохранились все уже установленные программы, их настройки, пути сохранений этих программ.

Я загрузил видео что имею ввиду по программе Tabs Bool и что имею ввиду, когда арлыки находятся на своем месте на рабочем столе .

Comment: Реестр тоже собрались сохранять?

Comment: Вы уже задавали такой вопрос, не зачем создавать такой же

Comment: Поддержу @danilshik. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/867267/191416 вопрос задан, люди пришли, проявили интерес и готовы помочь (минимум я), а ты молчишь в старой теме и плодишь дубликаты. Некрасиво.

Answer (score 0):

Идеальный вариант решения для Вас - создание образа своей системы

Comment: А если у него места свободного нет? А если он для вебдева юзает пхпшторм, гит4вин и докер овер гиперв? Стоит прям брать и делать дамп всего раздела?

Comment: @don Rumata тогда из готового образа удаляем все ненужное с помощью соответствующих утилит.

Comment: Эммм... Как ты себе представляешь удаление софта винды без помощи самой винды, которая запакована в архив?

Comment: @donRumata не софта. Предполагается, что весь установленный софт - нужен. Удалять любые другие файловые данные.

Comment: Слишком размыто. А если в систему пара современных игр установлена? Чё тогда? Это я про фразу "идеальный вариант решения".

Comment: @donRumata Я обычно делаю бэкапы имиджами, когда устанавливаю новую систему и устанавливаю в неё необходимое ПО. И, судя, по имеющемуся описанию от ТС, у него установлено все необходимое ПО, которое и желает сохранить, но не игрушки

Comment: А вот тут вообще бабка надвое сказала, т.е. в прошлой теме он вообще ничего не рассказал. Как впрочем и в этой.

Comment: @donRumata об чем и речь

Comment: Ну вот поэтому я и зацепился за твой "идеальный вариант".